# How to export multiple excels based on one column

Tags: excel, pandas, export

I was trying to export multiple excels based on the value of one column. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['PA','PA','TX','TX'],'county':['Centre','Berks','Austin','Taylor'],'a':[4,3,2,1],'b':[3,4,5,6]})
df
```

How can I export this dataframe to multiple excels based on the attribute of column "state". For example, to export a separate excel only with "state" = "PA" and another excel with "state" = "TX". Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to select the rows to export to each excell based on state?

Comment: `df[df['state'].eq('PA')].to_excel('excel1.xlsx')`

Comment: `df[~df['state'].eq('PA')].to_excel('excel2.xlsx')`

Comment: Yes, it works. Two following questions: 1. Why add "~" sign, I tried with and without the "~", both works. 2. Imagine I have a long list on the column "state", how to write a loop to export all the Excels with the name corresponding to the value. For example, TX.xlsx for the state=TX

Comment: please, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution for n elements in the `state` column.**

**1.imagine that this is your dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['PA','PA','TX','TX','RX'],'county':['Centre','Berks','Austin','Taylor','Mike'],'a':[4,3,2,1,0],'b':[3,4,5,6,7]})
print(df)
```

---

```
  state  county  a  b
0    PA  Centre  4  3
1    PA   Berks  3  4
2    TX  Austin  2  5
3    TX  Taylor  1  6
4    RX    Mike  0  7
```

---

**2.the idea: [Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)**

```
df['state'].unique()

array(['PA', 'TX', 'RX'], dtype=object)
```

as you can see [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) returns the different and unrepeatable elements present in the series.

---

**3. For loop**

you can use a `for loop` to filter the dataframe based on the [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) `state` elements returned by unique:

```
for state in df['state'].unique():
    print(df[df['state'].eq(state)])
    print('-'*20)
```

---

```
      state  county  a  b
0    PA  Centre  4  3
1    PA   Berks  3  4
--------------------
  state  county  a  b
2    TX  Austin  2  5
3    TX  Taylor  1  6
--------------------
  state county  a  b
4    RX   Mike  0  7
```

---

**4 send to excel**

```
for state in df['state'].unique():
    df[df['state'].eq(state)].to_excel(state+'.xlsx')
```

**on the use of [DataFrame.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), [DataFrame.ne](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and the operator `~`**

My suggestion in your comment on the use of ~ is because there were only two states.

the following expressions are equivalent:

```
~df.eq(a)
 df.ne(a)
```